# Visual Studio 2022 and ArcGIS Desktop 10.8

Tags: arcmap, visual-studio, arcgis-10.8

I am using a VS2022 solution to fire up ArcMap 10.8, but it always gives me this error:
[image]

I have updated VS2022, I have tried everything but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Any rights issues? Did you install both softwares for all users and not a specific one? Did you try running VS2022 as an admin to see if the problem persists?

Comment: I ran as Admin, issue still exists, yes its installed for all users,  no rights issue I am pretty sure, its runs fine on VS2019

Comment: It seems ArcObjects 10.8 SDK is compatible only upto VS2019 , on the link below, they dont mention anything beyond 2019, can anyone verify this https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcobjects-sdk-system-requirements.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_134116909B4B4DB888C65AF8FC67CAB9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing VS2022 Professional helped me resolve the issue - I had VS2022 Enterprise before